# Issue with NSTreeController moveNode:toIndexPath:?

Tags: objective-c, nstreecontroller

I'm using an `NSTreeController` set in entity mode, to manage a hierarchy of folders (a core data entity I call `Folder`). The "Children" key path is set to an `NSArray` readwrite property of `Folder`, which I call `subfoldersArray`. (I use `NSArray` because `NSOrderedSet` doesn't work with a tree controller).

When the user moves a folder to another folder (via an `NSOutlineView`) or at a different position of the same parent folder, the app calls  `moveNode:toIndexPath:` on the tree controller. I use this method as it preserves the selection (while changing the underlying model tends to deselect the selected folder, even though the controller has `preserveSelection` set to `YES`.

Problem: every `Folder` instance that is moved by `moveNode:toIndexPath:` is placed at the end of the `subfoldersArray`, regardless of the index path specified.
This happens only when the `NSTreeController` controls an `NSManagedObject` subclass (in either class or entity mode).

The exact same `moveNode:toIndexPath:` instruction on the same `NSTreeController` controlling an equivalent `NSObject` subclass (with an identical `subfoldersArray` property) works as expected.

I'd like a solution that doesn't involve setting the underlying model myself, as this tends to deselect the selected folder (which may not be the one that is moved).

Comment: Is the issue reproducable in a small test project without Core Data?

Comment: See my edits. I found that the issue only happens if the tree controller controls an `NSManagedObject` subclass. Very weird. I can provide a link to a small project if you want to test.

Comment: NSManagedObject is an interface to Core Data, yes? Well, Core Data thinks entirely in sets; there is no such thing as an array as far as Core Data is concerned. So I would not expect an inserted object to be at _any_ particular position in an array that is being read into Core Data and back; the array-ness (i.e. the order) would be destroyed by such an operation. The usual thing (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123519/does-core-data-persist-the-order-of-objects-in-nsmutablearray) is to give your entities a property _you_ can sort on as you retrieve the set.

Comment: ^ This is what I'm doing by using an `NSArray` property rather than a set (`NSTreeController` doesn't work with ordered sets). But why would `NSTreeController` set the array property differently depending on the class of the object it manages?

Comment: Experiment: implement `addSubfoldersArrayObject:`, `removeSubfoldersArrayObject:` and the other Core Data relationship methods on `Folder`.

Comment: `subfoldersArray` is not a core data relationship since it is an NSArray. Anyway, I can modify the underlying model just fine, no problem. But when I do, the selected folder in the outline view gets deselected (even though the tree controller is set to maintain the selection.) I can re-select the folder in code just after the change, but its content (which can be other entities) still get deselected. This doesn't happen if I use `moveNode:toIndexPath:`, but then the underlying model is not in sync. I ended up calling `moveNode:toIndexPath`: and changing the underlying model as well.

Comment: If the problem is solved, give the solution in the Answer field, or delete the question. Thanks.

Comment: I clarified the solution I'm looking for. It's still not found. And I'm not sure why the issue was downvoted. Do Apple state that `moveNode:toIndexPath:` would always place the moved item at the end of the destination array if this array just happens to be a property of some `NSManagedObject` subclass? I don't think so.

Comment: If I let Xcode generate a NSManagedObject subclass the I get a category `CoreDataGeneratedAccessors` with `insertObject:inSubfoldersAtIndex:`, `removeObjectFromSubfoldersAtIndex:` etc. Implement these methods for `subfoldersArray` and modify `folders`. (It's a hack)

Comment: I tried modifying the underlying model myself (not easy). The selection is preserved except when it's the dragged item(s).

Comment: Thanks for testing. I use the methods you mention to modify the underlying model. The problem is that doing so does not preserve the selection in all situations.